# Raster Image Tiles created using GDAL2Tiles (from GDAL 2.4.2) does not align properly with Open Street Map Tile layer

Tags: gdal, leaflet, openstreetmap, gdal2tiles

I am trying show a custom tile overlay (created from a raster image) on top of openstreetmap base layer using Leaflet.

I used one of the raster images from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/10m-natural-earth-1/
and used GDAL2Tiles (I have GDAL 2.4.2.) to create a tile layer.

```
gdal2tiles.py -p raster -z 0-8 NE1_HR_LC.tif Natural
```

The generated tiles are not aligned properly with openstreetmap as base layer. I have attached an image on how it appears when both of the layers appear.[image: Custom tile layer and openstreetmap tile layer]

Below is the code in the front end.

```
let minzooms =0;
let maxzooms =8;
let beginzooms =3;

var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors', minZoom: minzooms, maxZoom: maxzooms});

var lyr = L.tileLayer('/tiles/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png', {tms: true, opacity: 0.7, attribution: "tiled map", minZoom: minzooms, maxZoom: maxzooms, noWrap: true });

var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [40.86667, 34.56667],
        zoom: beginzooms,
        minZoom: minzooms,
        maxZoom: maxzooms,
        layers: [osm]
    });

 var basemaps = {"OpenStreetMap": osm};
 var overlaymaps = {"Layer": lyr};

 L.control.layers(basemaps, overlaymaps, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);

 map.fitBounds([[-180, -90], [180, 90]]);
```

Is gdal2tiles causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to match two different map projections.

The default OpenStreetMap tiles use the EPSG:3857 coordinate reference system, AKA Web [Mercator Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection). It looks like this:

[image: mercator projection example]

On the other hand, the Natural Earth files use the EPSG:4326 coordianate reference system, AKA [equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection). It looks like this:

[image: equirectangular projection example]

The issue of [map projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection), [reference ellipsoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_ellipsoid) and how those combine to form [coordinate reference systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) is not trivial if you're new to the GIS field. If you're asking yourself "which is the best projection", the answer is "all of them" (each for a different purpose).

In your particular case, you want `gdal2tiles` to generate epsg:3857 "mercator" tiles from a epsg:4326 raster source, reprojecting the data during the process.

So, tell `gdal2tiles` that you want mercator tiles with...

```
-p mercator
```

...and tell that the source raster is in EPSG:4326 with...

```
-s epsg:4326
```

...and everything together should look like:

```
gdal2tiles.py -z 0-8 -p mercator -s epsg:4326 NE1_LR_LC.tif Natural
```

Remember to run `gdal2tiles.py --help` for more info about command-line parameters.

Comment: thank you for the explanation.  Adding -p mercator -s espg:4326 generated blank tiles though. Not sure why it didn't work.  Adding following options  seem to generate correct tiles which aligned with openstreetmap as well. gdal2tiles.py -z 0-8 -a 0,0,0 -e NE1_LR_LC.tif Natural.